# What is the Meaning of this code??specially View's role in it??it is an android code?

Tags: android-view

Code goes like this

```
Button next;
next =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a button called "next", it is really a rename of the already existing button R.id.button1 . The method that listens to click events (setOnClickListener) has a method that gets called when the button is actually clicked (onClick), within "onClick(View v)" you want to put all the things that you want the program to do when the button is clicked.

Comment: View would be the object that has the listener method and there is a View object that contains the initial "next" button..  It looks like Java, but I can't say for certain that it's Android code.